# Unable to run appium tests on Android 7.0

Tags: android, appium

I have problem with running tests on Android 7.0 real device (Nexus 6)
Appium version: 1.6.3
OS: Windows 10
Language: Java
Java client: 4.1.2

What's interesting, when I plug in any Android 6 device (setting platformVersion to 6.0) - the tests are running without a problem. But when I try to run them on Android 7.0 device I get the error.

Here are my capabilities for running on Android 7.0:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.0");
capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", true);
capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 0);
capabilities.setCapability("app", "C:\Apk\xxx-release.apk");
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.xxx.android.vvm");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.xxx.android.vvm.activity.Splash");
```

Here are the logs from IDE console output:

```
    Feb 14, 2017 4:21:19 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Feb 14, 2017 4:21:24 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.
Feb 14, 2017 4:21:29 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{app=C:\Apk\xxx-release.apk, appPackage=com.xxx.android.vvm, appActivity=com.xxx.android.vvm.activity.Splash, newCommandTimeout=0, platformVersion=7.0, browserName=Android, platformName=Android, deviceName=Android, fullReset=true, autoAcceptAlerts=true}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'TAC-45', ip: '10.3.184.68', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:91)
```

And here are the server logs:

```
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Not cleaning generated files. Add clearSystemFiles capability if wanted.
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C\:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZX1G22D7HJ install C\:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\bin\settings_apk-debug.apk' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'Failed to install C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\bin\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package io.appium.settings signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!]'; Code: '1'
at ADB.execFunc$ (../../../lib/tools/system-calls.js:195:13)
at tryCatch (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:67:40)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke as _invoke
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) as throw
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:136:37)
at process.tickCallback (internal/process/nexttick.js:103:7)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 4879 ms - 754
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"C:\Apk\xxx-release.apk","appPackage":"com.xxx.android.vvm","appActivity":"com.xxx.android.vvm.activity.Splash","newCommandTimeout":0,"platformVersion":"7.0","browserName":"Android","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Android","fullReset":true,"autoAcceptAlerts":true},"requiredCapabilities":{}}}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Bad parameters: BadParametersError: Parameters were incorrect. We wanted {"required":["desiredCapabilities"],"optional":["requiredCapabilities","capabilities","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id"]} and you sent ["capabilities"]
```

It appears that there is an error with capabilities. However when I plug in a phone with Android 6 and set platformVersion to 6.0 all tests are running without a problem!

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove "Unlock" and "Appium settings" apps from device - Appium installs those apps automatically. (In my cause those apps were not compatible after updating Android from version 6 to version 7.

Comment: This deserves more "arrow ups".
Helped me for sure

Answer (score 0):

Could you post Java-Client version ?

Note: Try the latest stable Java-client version.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/4.1.2

Comment: Yep, I've got 4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "**app**" capability which tries to install every time on the device. Instead, install the app manually once on the device and try. If it doesn't work let me know there is one more solution, but I suggest you to try this first.

Comment: Removing the "app" capability didn't help. It shows the same errors

Answer (score 0):

As error logs shows

```
[INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package io.appium.settings signatures do not match the previously installed version;
```

Usually these error comes due to having a signed release version on device, then trying to deploy the debug version on top. It gets stuck in an invalid state where it's not fully uninstalled.

Because of these reason your session is not created and to avoid these please uninstall application which exist on device and then run the script.It should work.

Hope these help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. And again, I was able to run tests on Android 6 no matter whether the app installed or not. I think the problem is in this:
' Bad parameters: BadParametersError: Parameters were incorrect. We wanted {"required":["desiredCapabilities"],"optional":["requiredCapabilities","capabilities","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id"]} and you sent ["capabilities"]'

But I couldn't find the answer what exactly is wrong

Comment: okey then you should try with minimum parameter try with minimum capabilities which you have doubt and run the script

Answer (score 0):

If you run into this error uninstall all artifacts from your test device using Android Studio. Open the Gradle view on the right hand side of Android studio.

Open :app > Tasks > install and run the uninstallAll task by double clicking it